# python package hierarchy fails to load depending on the directory I'm in

Tags: python

I have a python package I'm writing that looks like this:

```
ls -R ~/foobar/
__init__.py
foo.py
bar/
bar/__init__.py
bar.py
```

In `foo.py` I have the following pseudocode. The real coding is more complicated so let's not get into the fact that in what's below, I don't actually need to call `bar()`

```
import sys
from bar import bar 

def foo(X,y):
     for i,x in enumerate(X):
         X[i]= y * bar(x)
```

and let's say that `bar.py` has:

```
import numpy as np
def bar(X):
    return np.cos(X)
```

If I am in the `foobar/` directory, from within the python interpreter I can use

```
>>> !pwd
/home/me/foobar
>>> from foo import foo
```

And everything works fine. But if I go into a different directory and try the following, I get an error:

```
>>> !pwd
/home/me/bin
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/home/me/foobar')
>>> from foo import foo
ImportError: No module named bar
```

Now I can fix this by changing my import statement in `foo.py` to:

```
from .bar import bar
```

And it works. But then when I go back into the `foobar/` directory and try the import, it fails:

```
>>> !pwd
/home/me/foobar/
>>> from foo import foo
---> 28 from .bar import bar
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Ugh! I've tried adding `'.'` and `'..'` into the path at the head of the `foo.py` and `bar.py` files but it didn't work. I've tried explicitly saying in the `__init.py__` files to load what is in the directory, i.e.

```
cat foobar/__init__.py
from foo import *
```

Again, no luck. I'm definitely missing something and I have no idea what it is...

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but the short answer is that this is working as intended. You can either have a bunch of Python scripts that import shared libraries in a package structure, or you can have a bunch of independent Python scripts that happen to be deployed in a particular directory structure (but don't import from each other); you can't have both. (Not without some crazy hacking of low-level import stuff.)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Naively, I would have thought that no matter the directory from which you load the topmost code, it would work the same. I guess not...  By the way, I hunted all over SO and couldn't find this particular question asked/answered, but i'm happy for someone to show me otherwise.

Comment: If your application is composed of multiple packages, the intended way to execute a module from within it is to use `python -m dotted.path.to.module` and not `python path/to/module.py` or worse `cd path/to/module; python ./module.py`. I know I've seen this discussed before but I'm having trouble finding a good duplicate at the moment.

Comment: Also: The really "right" way to do this is to write a `setup.py` for your project that will install the "library" parts of it into `site-packages` and the "script" parts of it into `bin`, and then use `pip` to install it all into the right place(s).